# How can I prove ownership of hardware wallet?

Tags: public-key, signature, cryptocurrency

I’m applying for a mortgage loan and I recently made a large deposit into my bank account from crypto stored on a ledger hardware wallet .  I sent the funds to Coinbase where I converted to usd and withdrew into my bank account.

The mortgage lender is giving me trouble about providing proper documentation. I mined most of it a few years ago so I don’t have a record of purchase.

Is there anyway that I can provide proof that I own the original source wallet?

Comment: Isn't all transactions are on the web? I think this question better suits either Bitcoin.SE, Ethereum.SE. It is specific to their protocol.

Comment: I can show all transactions on the blockchain but can’t prove that the private key used to sign them belongs to me.  I could prove it by sending a small amount but the bank is having a tough time understanding any of this

Comment: I should be able to sign a message including date/time stamp along with the address but I ca't find this functionality in Ledge Live software.  It used to be there (According to what I have been reading).

Comment: did you ever figure this out? Running into the same problem with my lender. I moved usdt from my cold wallet to coinbase and then to my bank. Lender is making this hard even though i have an 820 fico and nothing questionable on any accounts

Comment: This question was closed because it's not about a cryptographic problem. It's a legal problem, or one related to practice around Bitcoin, thus off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is find some document that associates you with the virtual or hardware wallet. The most obvious way is the receipt you used to purchase the physical wallet. If you didn't keep the receipt, the company you bought it from may be willing and able to help you.

Comment: That proves I own a hardware wallet but not that it was used to sign the transactions.  I’m thinking the only way would be to send another transaction